# Programatically perfrom maven install phase using java

Tags: java, maven

How can I programmatically perform maven install phase from java code?
I am using mojo class and able to programmatically drilled down till build.
Concern is how to add the jars into maven local repository ?

Comment: Why not call Maven as a Process in Java?

Comment: That is OK ! But my pom file does'not have any information about jars present in project . If I am using Maven as a project I wont be able to add all dependent jar in maven repository.

Comment: @RishabhKhandelwal The jars where you mean the dependencies must be present in your repository manager and why are you not able add the needed jars into your maven repository...than your setup is wrong.

Comment: You need to elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve and what your current setup is. That will allow us to give you better help.